# Expressing time duration or time when and within

Tags: grammar-choice, time, numerals

I'm studying Oxford Latin Course. The book said that duration of time takes the accusative and time when and within take the ablative case. I can understand that, but does duration of time and time within take cardinal and time when take ordinal? Like, *tres horas* = “for three hours,” *decem diebus* = “within ten days”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly right:

> Dominus creavit caelum et terram sex diebus.
> Septimo die requievit ab operibus suis.
>
> *The Lord created heaven and earth in six days.* (i.e., within, over the course of six days)
> *On the seventh day he rested from his work.*

Answer (score 2):

decem diebus is "time within which" yet decem is a cardinal number. So I think within which can take either ordinal or cardinal numbers with it.

Comment: Can you give an example with an ordinal as well?